# iOS Firebase Crashlytics :: Test crash from simulator appears, but real crash from device doesn't

Tags: ios, firebase, crash, crashlytics

**Situation:**

The app (installed via Testflight) crashed on the device. The crash can't be reproduced.

**Problem:**

The crash information doesn't appear on the firebase crashlytics dashboard, but it did appear in the Apple crash logs, now available through the Xcode Organizer.

**The *weird* stuff:**

- forcing a crash (`Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`) works (in simulator at least) and the crash appears in the dashboard.
- `DWARF with dSYM File` is configured for all targets, both debug & release.
- `archive` configuration seems the same as `run` for all schemas/targets.

Any ideas as to what may be the problem, or what else I could try, will be greatly appreciated. I want to exhaust all the possibilities before we can claim it was *just a fluke*.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you upload dSYM on Firebase Crashlytics?

Comment: Jeez... you are right, I was sure I had submitted it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whoever have the same problem, you have to upload your dSYM on Firebase to avoid missing or incomplete crash information.

Comment: I'm adding that some time ago the crashes did appear in the dashboard, but you just couldn't see the trace... Now the crash doesn't even appear until you've uploaded the dSYM ¯\_(ツ)_/¯